# Looking for a tool that can read logs dynamically and display it to the screen during runtime

Tags: c#, logging

I created a software, and i also print to logs.
I am Looking for a tool that can read the logs dynamically and display it to the screen dynamically as the log changes in run-time

I also want to mention that i am using log4net, and i know that you can print to console using log4net.
the problem with log4net is that there is a limitation that you cannot print to console in WPF, so every tool will be fine

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [Baretail](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/) is the preeminent tool in this category.

That said, I don't think there is any limitation with log4net and WPF. Of course, if you are running a WPF application, it is not a console application, so logging to the console is meaningless. If you want to add a log visualizer to your WPF application, you can create a log4net appender to wire that up.

Comment: Until Baretail has a search option I still think the [less](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/less.htm) pager is still a better option for perusing logs.

Comment: @PaulRuane A search option? Baretail has amazing RegEx-enabled search capability.

Comment: I'm not talking about highlighting. Certainly the last time I looked at it (which wasn't all that long ago) one could highlight but not search.

Comment: @PaulRuane I see that this is a feature of BareTail Pro; it has been a while since I used the free version. http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretailpro/index.php

Answer (score 0):

What if you change Log4Net to log to a database instead of a text file?

You can then use your WPF application to read the database entries and display them. You could do this using polling (check each X seconds if there is a new item) or you could use [SqlDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx) so that Sql notifies you when there is a change in your logging table (push model, which will perform better).

Comment: actually what i do need is that the Console feature of log4net will be working. i want a console and logs printed dynamically so i can know what is happening in real time without opening the text file